# Simplest way in FAKE to restore packages with a source

Tags: f#-fake, f#-fake-4

I was wondering what is the simplest way to restore packages when there is an alternative source.
I tried

```ml
Target "RestorePackages" (fun _ ->
!! "./**/packages.config"
    |> Seq.iter (RestorePackage (fun p ->
        { p with Sources = ["http://mysource.com"]}))
```

)

This works locally but I was wondering if there is a way to call

```ml
RestorePackages()
```

without having to set up nuget configuration?
Is there any other (nicer)way ?

Comment: yes. at the moment you have to use your first approach.

Comment: Thanks @forki23 I thought I was missing something obvious :D